# How to configure nginx for two static folder

Tags: node.js, nginx

Here I have nginx configuration for my both apps. 
You can see I have comments in place where I need  help.

```
upstream node1 {
        server localhost:2053;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration

#        ssl on;
         ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/CA/cert/mycert.pem;
         ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/CA/key/mykey.key;
         listen 443 ssl default_server;
         listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        server_name myPublicIP;

        location / {
                root /home/ubuntu/app1/public;
                index index.html index.htm
                proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|mp3|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
        //Here I need create root for two apps,which are in defferent paths 
        //1st in /home/ubuntu/app1/public and second in /home/ubuntu/app2/public 

        }
        location /users/register {
                root /home/ubuntu/app1/public;
                index index.html index.htm;
                proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/users/register;
        }

    location /users/authenticate {
            root /home/ubuntu/app1/public;
            index index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/users/authenticate;
    }
    location /users/home {
            root /home/ubuntu/app1/public;
            index index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/users/home;
    }



    location /game {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            root /home/ubuntu/app2/public;
            index index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass https://node1/;


    }
```

Here I need to set something like script, that looking for if location is /game/ to serve static files from app2 which is running on different port.For other locations server must serve static files from app1.Without nginx both works fine. How I can solve this problem.Thanks for help and for attention.

Comment: That is confusing. Given that would be possible: How do you expect nginx to decide what asset to deliver if there is a match in both roots?

Comment: So if I have 2 different apps how I can use them under nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got this right, you need static files being served from /home/ubuntu/app2/public when the user is in the /game/ url, and from /home/ubuntu/app1/public elsewhere. Did I get this right?

If so, you should probably make two different `location` like the ones you already wrote. Something like

```
location ~* ^\/game\/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|mp3|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm))$ {
    root /home/ubuntu/app2/public;
    try_files $1 $1/ =404;
}

location ~* ^(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|mp3|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm))$ {
    root /home/ubuntu/app1/public;
    try_files $1 $1/ =404;
}
```

This is untested, but it should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for reply GavinoGrifoni. This variant will work too,but I've created new location for first app and both apps work in different locations /app1/ and /app2/. I thought that using / location will bring some troubles in future because / directory contains /game/ directory too.And what about / location,right now it just redirect it to /app1/ maybe I'll do with it something else.So Thank you very much one more time))))))))))

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use an upstream on your location /games
Check out this: https://serverfault.com/questions/823234/use-nginx-upstream-group-with-multiple-ports

edit: I just saw youre using upstream already. But your upstream is probably listening on port 443 and not on port 2053 since youre proxy passing to

Comment: I need to serve static files (jpg,mp3,gif etc.) from different static folders for different apps,but in one host.Thanks in any case))))))

Comment: This my third day since I'm using nginx.So you can find some mistakes in my configuration.I have socket.io in my app2 I read that its good practice to use upstream for app that running with sockets.